# Regex pattern containing substring and no withespaces

Tags: regex, angular, validation, pattern-matching, regex-alternation

I want to validate an input form in Angular, string must contain substring:

```
facebook.com
```

or

```
fb.me
```

and

```
no whitespaces
```

so for instance:

```
1) randomString -> Fail
2) www.facebook.com -> Ok
3) www.fb.me -> Ok
4) www.facebook.com/pippo pallino -> Fail (there is a withespace after the word "pippo")
```

for the first 3 I have some working pattern:

```
pattern = '^.*(?:facebook\\.com|fb\\.me).*$';
```

but this is not validating the fourt one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern = '^\\S*(?:facebook\\.com|fb\\.me)\\S*$';
```

Or, with a regex literal notation:

```
pattern = /^\S*(?:facebook\.com|fb\.me)\S*$/;
```

Here, `.*` is replaced with `\S*` that matches 0 or more non-whitespace characters.

See the [**regex demo online**](https://regex101.com/r/jJptQh/2).